# Loading jQuery inside an ES5 strict mode function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to import jQuery inside an IIFE scope like this:

```js
(function (window, document) {
    "use strict";
    /* Content of jquery.min.js goes here */
    /* Code that uses $ goes here */
}(window, document));
```

Now, I'm running into a strict mode violation as soon as this code runs, possibly because jQuery itself doesn't conform:

> In strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or
>   immediately within another function.

Is there a way to load jQuery just inside a single function scope, while still retaining strict mode for the rest of the code that relies on it?

Comment: I realize that it may not be possible to load jQuery in a isolated scope, as it always touches window.jQuery and window.$, and therefore be global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1779

> jQuery isn't meant to be run with "use strict" in effect. See the comment at the top of the unminified file for the reason, or look at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13335 for more information. You are not gaining anything by attempting to force jQuery into strict mode against its will, doing so prevents interoperability with any third-party libraries that are not use-strict compatible.